# Create pitch changing code?

Tags: iphone, audio

Does anyone know how I could record some audio on the iphone then change the pitch of the audio?

Comment: Unless you wonder how to create an app to do that, the question probably belongs on superuser.com.

Answer (score 2):

Download and use the [I-AM-T-Pain application](http://gizmodo.com/5352299/i-am-t+pain-iphone-app-is-auto+tuning-genius) ;-)

Comment: Good answer for superuser.com, but not terribly helpful if he's looking to write his own pitch changer...

Comment: @Matt the "semicolon-dash-parens" sequence often signifies a joke. For example, ;-)

Comment: @Rexm actually ;-) is the endline character in the HappyEnding++ programming language

Comment: I have not found the T-Pain app to be nearly autotuney enough. I wanted my money back instantly.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you'll want to start with the Core Audio Framework: http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/

There doesn't seem to be a whole wealth of information on the AutoTune algorithm, but a good start would be to use a Fast Fourier Transform to analyze the pitch to determine what pitch your audio is actually at.  It's a relatively simple to change the pitch from what it is to what it needs to be.  For example, A is 440 Hz.  Assuming the input is actually 466.164 (A#), and you want it to be A, you adjust the waveform by 0.94387383 (440 / 466.16400).  An A# becomes an A.

If you want to achieve an auto tune effect, you'll want to subdivide the recording into tiny audio clips that you can re-pitch individually.

More info on pitch detection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm